# A Synapse Trigger created via azure cli is missing in Synapse UI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-synapse

EDIT:
This is a Workspace that is connected to a git repository.
If I am adding triggers to a Workspace that is in "Live"-mode, the triggers will show. How can I add triggers to a workspace that is setup to a git repo?

Using Azure Synapse, I had some issues when publishing the workspace after creating and deleting some triggers.

I decided to delete all triggers in the UI, and then publish worked fine.

To avoid having to recreate the trigges in the UI, I wanted to create the triggers through the azure commandline, but the triggers I create do not show up in the Synapse UI.

I am creating a Synapse trigger through the azure commandline:

```bash
az synapse trigger create --workspace-name wsname --name triggername --file @"path/trigger.json"
```

Listing the triggers through the cli shows the newly created trigger:

```bash
$ az synapse trigger list --workspace-name wsname
[
  {
    "etag": "sometag",
    "id": "/subscriptions/subscription/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/wsname/triggers/triggername",
    "name": "triggername",
    "properties": {
      "additionalProperties": null,
      "annotations": [],
      "delay": "00:00:00",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "description": null,
      "endTime": "2022-08-17T08:32:00+00:00",
      "frequency": "Hour",
      "interval": 24,
      "maxConcurrency": 50,
      "pipeline": {
        "parameters": null,
        "pipelineReference": {
          "name": null,
          "referenceName": "Pipelinename",
          "type": "PipelineReference"
        }
      },
      "retryPolicy": {
        "count": null,
        "intervalInSeconds": 30
      },
      "runtimeState": "Stopped",
      "startTime": "2022-08-17T06:32:00+00:00",
      "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger"
    },
    "resourceGroup": "rg",
    "type": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/triggers"
  }
]
```

If I look in Synapse UI, under Synapse > Manage > Triggers, it shows "No triggers to display..."

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that the Synapse Workspace was setup using a Git Repository.
To add the triggers, it was as simple as adding them to the repository, and pushing the changes.

If it is setup in Live-mode, the azure cli commands works fine.